# What is the difference between localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare: and caseInsensitiveCompare:?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I was going to use the following line of code:

```
[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

'caseInsensitiveCompare' is a method that I'm used to using on strings. But, the example shown that I was working from uses:

```
[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

(the difference being the word localized). What does this word do - how is the 'localized' method different to the normal method?

The Apple developer documentation is not very informative as to how these two methods differ.

Comment: It's just a localization-method (meaning that if your app has more than one language, you should use it).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

NSString provides both methods, caseInsensitiveCompare and localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare.

Certain locales may define different sorting criteria.  If you are working with text localized for various locales, then use the localized version.  Otherwise, use the standard version.

Answer (score 15):

This means that the comparator uses the national character sets when comparing.
In example polish language has letter Ł, which, in the national charaters set, is between L and M.

In example, when we have strings: Ltest, Łtest, Mtest, Ztest strings:

caseInsensitiveCompare gives in result: Ltest, Mtest, Ztest, Łtest
localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare gives in result: Ltest, Łtest, Mtest, Ztest

Answer (score 5):

`localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:` is a localized version of `caseInsensitiveCompare:`. As it makes no much difference in English locale, it does e.g. in Polish for `ł, ą, ę`, etc or in Spanish for `ñ, é, á`, etc or French for `ç, è, ê`, etc. They have different position in alphabet depending on the locale.

Answer (score 5):

The `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:` method is going to use any rules present for the current locale (`[NSLocale currentLocale]`) when sorting your data.  These rules will often include numbering precedence, non-ASCII character ordering, and more.

Basically, unless you are expecting ordering based on character code, you should be using the localized method.

If you have not worked with localization before, I would recommend checking out the following links:

- [Internationalization and Localization for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171-SW1)
- [Localization Quick Reference](http://www.fluxforge.com/blog/localizing-iosos-x-apps-quick-reminder)