# CoreData sorting is treating single straight quote and single smart quote as the same, how to treat them differently?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nssortdescriptor

I've got a CoreData database and I'm fetching a list of Animals from it, sorted by a `namesortable` field. But namesortables that start with `'` and with `` ` `` are being treated as if they are the same and producing results like this:

```
'affirm'
‘california’
'grasshopper'
'no doubt"
‘relentless’
...
```

This wouldn't inherently be a problem, but I'm fetching these with an `NSFetchedResultsController` which is sectioned by `-namefirstletter` and it's crashing because the sections are out of order. It thinks the sections are out of order because it keeps switching back and forth between `'` and with `` ` ``.

I know that I could alter the `-namefirstletter` method to swap smart quotes for single quotes to bludgeon it into working, but I'd rather not have to start creating a longer and longer list of exception characters that I need to swap. I'd prefer to get CoreData to just sort the data without treating `'` and with `` ` `` as the same.

Any suggestions?

---

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:Animal.entityname inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSArray<NSSortDescriptor *> *sortdescriptors = @[
    [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:Animal.fieldname_namesortable 
        ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]
];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortdescriptors];


fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"..."];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray<Animal*> *animals = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Comment: If it was me, I'd sanitize the data before saving it, by either removing the quote marks or standardizing them on one type of quote mark. Or if I needed the original formatting for some reason, I'd add a secondary field with sanitized data and use that for sorting.

Comment: +1 for sanitising the data, but see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776781/what-is-the-difference-between-localizedcaseinsensitivecompare-and-caseinsensit

Comment: @TomHarrington Paulw11 As I mentioned in the post, I know that I can hardcode some exceptions to swap certain characters for other certain characters, but I'm not excited about a potentially growing list of exceptions. The underlying iOS code obviously has some way of treating them the same because that's what happens when the NSFetchRequest does it's work. But the NSFetchedResultsController does NOT treat them the same way which is what causes the crash. I would like to know how to have both of them do the same thing; either both treat them the same or neither treat them the same.

Comment: @KennyWyland I suspect that the way you do that is to file a bug with Apple and hope that a future release of iOS does what you need. In the meantime there are workarounds.